# Path of completely bounded maps has uniformly bounded cb norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-algebras, banach-algebras, operator-spaces

If $\phi_t:A\rightarrow B$ is completely bounded for $t\in[0,1]$, and $t\mapsto\phi_t(a)$ is continuous for each $a\in A$, is $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}||\phi_t||_{cb}$ finite? Here, $A$ and $B$ are operator spaces or operator algebras.

In the setting of Banach spaces and bounded maps, it seems like the uniform boundedness principle gives a positive answer (or does it?).